# Abstract proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology

I have been reading up on the topological proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.How can one prove it more abstractly?given that the polynomial is a map from topological field S to itself,what is are the additional properties S should satisfy for FTA to be true?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my intuiutve understanding of the winding number proof of the FTA:

Given a degree-$n$ polynomial $f(z) = a_nz^n + \cdots + a_1z + a_0$, for a "large enough" circle $\gamma_R:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$ (centered at the origin, radius $R$), the curve $f(\gamma_R(t))$ behaves basically like $a_n\gamma_R(t)^n$, going around the origin $n$ times.

For a "small enough" circle $\gamma_r$ (still centered at the origin, radius $r$), on the other hand, $f(\gamma_r(t))$ behaves much like $a_1\gamma_r(t) + a_0$, not necessarily going around the origin at all (and if it does go around the origin no matter how small $r$ is, then $a_0 = 0$, and $z = 0$ is a root of $f$).

As you continually increase the radius from $r$ to $R$, the number of times the corresponding $f(\gamma)$ goes around the origin must increase from $0$ to $n$. As the curve $f(\gamma)$ changes continuously with the radius, at some point it must therefore pass through the origin. Thus $f$ has a root.

The closedness of the curves $\gamma$ ensures that this increase in winding number cannot come from the end points themselves winding around the origin, the way you would wind a rope around a pole. Thus they must come from the curve actually passing through the origin at some stage.

More technically, the function from $[r,R]\to\Bbb N$ given by this winding number is continuous. And since it's not constant, it must be undefined at some points. The only way the winding number is undefined is if the curve passes through the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..i just realised I could phrase my question in a better way,as I wanted to know how deeply all the concepts used in the proof are linked to solutions of a polynomial..